# Python urllib3 doesn't seem to be sending fields data

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am trying to utilise the authentication here: https://api.graphnethealth.com/system-auth using Python urllib3 and have the following

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
resp = http.request(
        "POST",
        "https://core.syhapp.com/hpca/oauth/token",
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        fields={
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_id": "YYYYYYYYY",
            "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXX"
        }
    )
print(resp.data)
```

I get an error saying that `grant_type` has not been sent.

```
b'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "400",\r\n    "message": "Validation Errors",\r\n    "target": "/oauth/token",\r\n    "details": [\r\n      {\r\n        "message": "grant_type is required",\r\n        "target": "GrantType"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n        "message": "Value should be one of the following password,refresh_token,trusted_token,handover_token,client_credentials,pin",\r\n        "target": "GrantType"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: If you landed on this page troubleshooting a JSON POST, note that you need to change `fields` arg to `body`! The docs make this switcheroo without highlighting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it the data will be form-urlencoded, but that's not what `request` does by default.  I believe you need:

```
resp = http.request(
        "POST",
        "https://core.syhapp.com/hpca/oauth/token",
        fields={
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_id": "YYYYYYYYY",
            "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXX"
        },
        encode_multipart = False
    )
```

`request` replaces the `Content-Type` header, so there's no point in specifying it at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have specified wrong `Content-Type` header value. The request body is a JSON, so try with `Content-Type: application/json`.